# Count unique words in blog's article and save it in model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have blog with articles ( Article is model). Every article contains title and body. I need to add field, which contains list of unique words of that article and occurrence in the article. For example, article " Hello my name is John, hello", field "words" should looks like:

> {"hello": 2, "my": 1, "name":1, "is":1, "john":1}

Additionally, i should have endpoint, which returns ALL words from ALL articles and their occurrence.

**How I want to implement it:**

Add field "unique_words" (type JSONField) and default value "please wait, word's occurrence are being calculated...". Then add post save signals which via Celery will do all calcuration and update field "unique_words" with data like this

```
{"hello": 2, "my": 1, "name":1, "is":1, "john":1}
```

Also I add endpoint, which will retrieve unique_words from all articles and summarize them.

Is it best solution?  Could you please recommend something better?

Comment: You could make a related model `WordCount` with a `ForeignKey` to the `Article`, and with the word and count. This all depends a bit on what you want to *do* with this. If you wrap it in a `JsonField`, then except for PostgreSQL, most databases will not be able to make queries on the JSON object. But if that is not necessary, then JSON is probably just fine.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yup, I've thought about it, but wouldnt it overload DB?

Comment: mind that we do not store every *individual* word here, we store *per unique* word, the count. So this would result in 5 `ArticleWord` objects, that seems reasonable. After all it scales approximately the same with the length of the JSON column.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am wondering, is it possible to create model WordCount, which will responsible for occurrence one specific word in all articles?  For example, article_1 "Hello, Bob", article_2 "Hello, Hello Bob", and WordCount with name  Hello and fields article_1 = 1, article_2 = 2 ?

Comment: in that case you can make an `Article` model, a `Word` model, and `ArticleWord` which acts like the "through" model of a many-to-many between `Article` and `Word`, and with an extra column: the number of times that word occurs. So yes, this looks more or less like an m2m relation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you again! Last question - Is it good idea to calculate all  occurrence  and creating ArticleWord objects in background ( e.g Celery). And retrieving all words occurrence via GET request ( on backend we will just extract all  `Word` objects and calculate their occurrence)?